# How to deal with unstructured data in F# similar to Typescript

Tags: f#

In NodeJs/TYpescript  I can declare an interface

```
export interface IPageStatementLine {
  line: string
  sData: any
}
```

Then I can access the data in a function:

```
function test (lineData: IPageStatementLine) {
    let mytext = lineData.mydynamicProperty.innerProperty
}
```

In F# - obviously, there is a lot more strong typing and it's not as "loose"  as nodejs - but I want to know how I would achieve a similar thing in F#

```
type PageStatementLine = {
    line: string
    sData: ??  option
}
```

I have used option in the past for Some / None values but can I declare the type property somehow as unstructured?

let myValue = lineData.sData.someProperty.someOtherProperty.

Comment: You're looking for dynamic access operator. I've found [blog](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2010/02/05/using-and-abusing-the-f-dynamic-lookup-operator/) about it. Shortly: you can define your own operator `let (?)` and use it to access data in a "dynamic" way

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with the library `FSharp.Interop.Dynamic`. This is written to run in FSI hence the `#r`:

```
#r "nuget: FSharp.Interop.Dynamic"

open FSharp.Interop.Dynamic

("asdf"?Length:int) // returns 4

("asdf"?Length:string) // InvalidCastException

("asdf"?Foo:string) // Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Foo'

type PageStatementLine = {
    line: string
    sData: obj
}

let test (lineData: PageStatementLine) =
    let myText : string = lineData.sData?mydynamicProperty?innerProperty
    myText
```

This uses the `?` operator. As you can see from the examples above, you need to specify the return type that you expect after calling dynamic properties. If you specify the wrong type or any of the properties don't exist then you'll get an exception.